# Python recursive call for list elements

Tags: python, list, recursion, append

I've tried to create a rough implementation of g-means to break a sample down into clusters where the clusters are gaussian using recursion, but my program seems to be going in only one direction (downward). The input values of this method were a data set, X, and a list of centers.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to solve the recursive bit of this method (the last for loop and beyond). After all of the recursive calls, I want to have a list of centers in C that can be returned to the main method.

So here's what happens in the last for loop. I'm iterating through a list of clusters (found using my cluster centers), `clust`, that contain all the values in each cluster. I run a test to see if there is significant evidence that the values in each cluster are gaussian. If there is evidence, then I want to remove that cluster center and add two new centers above and below. I then want to run through another recursive call and then evaluate these new center to see if the clusters they match to are gaussian or not.

The problem is my program is only evaluating the lower center bound. It seems to never reach the upper center as though the return statement means the program will stop the upper center from ever being reached.

Does anyone know how I can get my method to cover both the lower and upper sides of the cluster? (The for loop usually only makes 1 iteration ( `for i in range(len(clust))`) even when the length of clust = 2.

Another problem I'm having is that my method is simply overwriting the centers list instead of adding to it with each recursive call.  Does anyone know how I can make recursive calls while appending to a list? I'm inserting items into the list and passing part of the list to a deeper level, but on return, I only get two values (both really low).

```
def gMean(X,C):
 label=vq.kmeans2(X,np.array(C))
 #take care of centers that do not match to clusters in kmeans2
 while(len(set(range(len(C))))!=len(set((label[1])))):
     emptyK=set(range(len(C)))- set(range(len(C))).intersection(set(label[1]))
     emptyK=list(emptyK)
     emptyK.reverse()
     for i in range(len(emptyK)):
         C.pop(emptyK[i])
     label=vq.kmeans2(X,np.array(C))

 #clust is a 2D list and holds all the values for given cluster
 clust=[[] for x in range(max(label[1])+1)]
 for i in range(len(label[1])):
     for j in range(len(clust)):
         if j==label[1][i]:
             clust[j].append(X[i])

 for i in range(len(clust)):
     transClust=np.transpose(clust[i])
     notGausFlag=False
     for j in range(len(transClust)):
         if stats.anderson(transClust[j])[1][2]<stats.anderson(transClust[j])[0]:
             notGausFlag=True
     if notGausFlag==True:
         upper,lower=findCenter(clust[i],C[i])
         C.pop(i)
         C.insert(i,upper)
         C.insert(i,lower)
         for j in range(len(clust[i])):
             clust[i][j]=clust[i][j].tolist()
         clust[i]=np.array(clust[i])
         return gMean(clust[i],C[i:i+2])
 if notGausFlag==False:
     return C
```

Comment: Are the data you are using somewhere available?

Comment: Yeah, sorry I wasn't sure if it would help to show the whole file or just the recursive call (where the problem arises). I used the iris dataset. from sklearn import datasets iris = datasets.load_iris() X=iris.data

Answer (score 0):

So I think I realize the error in my code I'm calling a recursive method and passing a cluster with two cluster centers, but when I go to step into the next level of the recursive loop, I only ever step in with the first center because the second one isn't reached in the for loop `(for i in range(len(closet)):`).

What I should have done was call the recursive method like this.

```
return gMean(clust[i],C[i])+gMean(clust[i],C[i+1])
```